# Delphi Modify Existing XML Document Structure

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing, tclientdataset

I have an existing XML Document with nested tables. I want to open it, read in and MODIFY the structure (i.e. add or delete columns/fields). Ignoring the nested tables, here's a complete XML test doc:

```
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
  <METADATA>
    <FIELDS>
      <FIELD attrname="StringField" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20" /> 
      <FIELD attrname="IntField" fieldtype="i4" /> 
    </FIELDS>
    <PARAMS CHANGE_LOG="1 0 4 2 0 4" /> 
  </METADATA>
  <ROWDATA>
    <ROW RowState="4" StringField="String" IntField="234" /> 
    <ROW RowState="4" StringField="234" IntField="24" /> 
  </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

The following code throws an exception on open that "testField" was not found, presumably because it doesn't exist in the underlying XML file.

```
ClientDataSet1.Close;

with TStringField.Create(ClientDataSet1) do 
begin
  FieldName := 'testField';
  DataSet := ClientDataSet1; 
end; 

with ClientDataSet1 do 
begin 
  CreateDataSet; 
  Open; 
end;
```

If I add:

```
with ClientDataSet1 do
begin
  FieldDefs.Clear;
  Fields.Clear;
end;
```

an exception isn't thrown, but the first two fields disappear and the new structure is not written to the XML doc file unless I enter some data.

```
<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
  <METADATA>
    <FIELDS>
      <FIELD attrname="testField" fieldtype="string" WIDTH="20" /> 
    </FIELDS>
    <PARAMS CHANGE_LOG="1 0 4" /> 
  </METADATA>
  <ROWDATA>
    <ROW RowState="4" testField="12321" /> 
  </ROWDATA>
</DATAPACKET>
```

Is there a standard or recommended way of adding a field to an existing XML doc without losing the data?

Cheers,
Tanner

Comment: Well, it depends. There are many options.

Comment: You should add to your q a minimal example of a complete XML document including your added field.  That sort of XML modification usually works without problem if done correctly, though you need to clear any persistent TFields and TFieldDefs on your CDS otherwise you may very well get the error you report.

Comment: And by all means, please keep it *minimal*, for example a single test dataset using just two fields. Don't post an entire massive XML dataset with 30 columns and 500 records.

Comment: David, such as....?

Comment: MartynA, I'm going to try clearing persistent fields and defs tomorrow. Thanks. Are there any links you can provide for examples? All the ones I ran across seemed to be for new XMLdocs, not expanding existing ones.

Comment: Jerry, so noted. I'm going to attempt again tomorrow with a simplified scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not quite going about this the right way;  for starters, CreateDataSet
completely removes whatever data was previously in the ClientDataSet

The next thing is that you don't want to be doing this with persistent Fields and/or
FieldDefs in place, so clear them while you're doing your changes.  Whether you create them afterwards is up to you, but if you are going to create TFields in code, you should create one for **every** field in the XML metadata, starting from an empty Fields list in the CDS.

The example project below should show you how to get what you're after.  It

- Loads the dataset from the XML in a TMemo, Memo1.  In mine, I just copied
  and pasted the XML from your q.  This step is basically to show that the dataset
  is correctly populated;
- Then, the code in `AddFieldToXML` adds the new field to the Metadata in the XML and
  copies the result to Memo2, and saves it to disk.  Note:  As written, it does not
  write any data to the new field, but you should be able to get the idea for how
  to do that from  `AddFieldToXML`.

Finally, it closes and reopens the CDS by loading it from the altered XML

Code:

```
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, ExtCtrls, DBCtrls, Grids, DBGrids, DB, DBClient, MSXML;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Memo2: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    ExistingFN : String;
    NewFN : String;
    procedure AddFieldToXML;
    procedure LoadNewData;
  end;
[...]
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExistingFN :=  'C:\Temp\Data.XML';
  NewFN := 'C:\Temp\NewData.XML';

  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(ExistingFN);

  CDS1.Fields.Clear;
  CDS1.FieldDefs.Clear;
  CDS1.LoadFromFile(ExistingFN);

end;

procedure TForm1.AddFieldToXML;
var
  XmlDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  NodeList : IXmlDOMNodeList;
  Node,
  NewNode : IXmlDomNode;
  E : IXmlDomElement;
  PathQuery : String;
begin
  PathQuery := '/DATAPACKET/METADATA/FIELDS';

  Memo2.Lines.Clear;
  XmlDoc := CoDOMDocument.Create; //CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDOMDocument;
  XmlDoc.Async := False;
  XmlDoc.LoadXML(Memo1.Lines.Text);
  if xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('XML Load error:' + xmlDoc.parseError.reason);

  NodeList := XmlDoc.documentElement.SelectNodes(PathQuery);

  if NodeList.length > 0 then begin
    E := XMLDoc.createElement('FIELD');
    NewNode := E as IXMLDomNode;
    E.setAttribute('attrname', 'testField');
    E.setAttribute('fieldtype', 'string');
    E.setAttribute('WIDTH', '20');
    NodeList.item[0].appendChild(NewNode);
  end;
  Memo2.Lines.Text := XMLDoc.documentElement.xml;
  Memo2.Lines.SaveToFile(NewFN);
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadNewData;
begin
  CDS1.Close;
  CDS1.Fields.Clear;
  CDS1.FieldDefs.Clear;
  CDS1.LoadFromFile(NewFN);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddFieldToXML;
  LoadNewData;
end;
```

Once you've saved the new XML to disk, you can load it into the CDS in the IDE by right-clicking the CDS and using `Load from MyBase file` (for D7, similar for later versions), and then create persistent TFields if you want.

The XML code is for the version of MSXML.Pas that came with D7, btw.  I tend to post code for D7 unless a later Delphi version is required by the q.

Comment: @user2765744: Well, did this help with your problem or not?